# AngularJS and PhantomJS without sudo access

Tags: angularjs, seo, phantomjs, headless-browser

I created a site using AngularJS because I thought it would speed up the process. Now it turned out to be a complete headache. SEO is essential for the site and apparently, despite being created by Google, AngularJS sites aren't crawlable.

I read this article that explains a way around it:
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

My question is: how do I install or run PhantomJS (or any other headless browser) without sudo access? If so, how do I do it?
I'm hosting the site on 1and1 with a small budget.

Comment: You can get a VPS for $5/mo.  That's not much more expensive than what you are probably paying now.

Comment: So the only way to get PhantomJS to work is with VPS?

Comment: No, I didn't say that.  I'm suggesting that rather than wasting a ton of time hacking in a solution on a host that will probably kill your long-running processes anyway, pay for a cheap VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Some web hosting plane allow you to run you own application (they provide shell access, and that's what you need)

here you are a couple of them

```
http://www.webfaction.com/
http://www.justhost.com/
http://www.site5.com/
```

Make sure to contact them and ask if they allow you to install and run phantomjs before buying your hosting plan

Regards